# Visual Studio Code missing dirty file indicator and highlight tabs doesn't work

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I have a dirty file in VS Code, I do not get the bullet in the file tab nor do I get the highlight bar above the tab. I turned on Highlight Modified Tabs in the settings with no effect. I also tried changing themes in case it was a color issue. I don't have any extensions that would interfere with these settings.

Has anyone experienced this? Do I need to completely uninstall VS Code?

Comment: That was an issue in the past, see https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/83416 but it was fixed for me in November 2019.  Are you running the latest version of vscode?

Comment: It's on auto-update, and it is currently at version: 1.41.1, which is the latest at the moment. This has been happening for several versions now.

Comment: Also, your link points to the dot missing when the highlight modifier is working. I don't see either the dot or the highlight at the top of the tab.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I had the same issue and just solved it with this answer:

> That was a hint. I realized what was the problem. Kind of weird. I had
>   modified the settings.json file manually, setting auto save to off,
>   but I realized that under the File menu at the top, Auto Save was
>   marked as active. My files were not auto saving, but VS detected as if
>   it were active. Unchecking Auto Save in the File menu did the trick.

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/23950

I clicked **File > [unchecked] Auto Save**

This fixed it for me.

Comment: That fixed it. Although that is not what you would expect. They should show as dirty until the auto-save does its job; unless it saves on every character.

Comment: I agree that it's a bit non-sensical, but I couldn't figure out what else to do either. I chalk this up to a "turn it off and on again" solution. \*sigh\*