# VS Code doesn't show unsaved mark

Tags: visual-studio-code

I don't have any information for my case. But my VS Code doesn't show the rounded dot that mark the file is unsaved now.

Have you ever had problem like this? And how to solve it?
I need the dot :D

Comment: do you have any extensions?

Comment: @DanielA.White Yes, I have. Here's all my extensions: C/C++ Extension Pack, Live Share, Live Share Audio, Remote Containers, Remote - SSH, Remote - SSH: Editing Configuration Files, Remote - WSL

Comment: what is `"workbench.editor.highlightModifiedTabs"` set to in your preferences?

Comment: @DanielA.White omg, I didn't know what "workbench.editor.highlightModifiedTabs" is, so I tried to search it. And while searching for it, I solved my problem. Just deactivate autosave. Thanks you, the dot is back!

Comment: Yes, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59511977/visual-studio-code-missing-dirty-file-indicator-and-highlight-tabs-doesnt-work