# VS Code doesnt show whether a file is saved or not

Tags: visual-studio-code, save

This may seem like a dumb question, but VS Code doesn't show the white dot indicating that the file is saved, it's annoying.

Before saving:

[image]

After Saving:

[image]

The X for "close tab" disappears to allow for the white dot to show when it's not saved but the white dot doesn't appear

Comment: Maybe try changing your theme

Comment: @PabloSarturi Tried that, still doest work (i tried it with the default vscode theme)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/59585768/836330, it may help.

Comment: @Mark no success :(